# Problems aligning css into middle

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues trying to align the error text center down in the middle of the screen, padding works but both of the `<h1>` start to separate in a large gap, I want it to be the same as it is now but in the center of the screen. All the `<div>` that say `display: none;` are used to hide the mobile navigation bar in desktop mode which works correctly.

```css
.nav2 {
   display: none;  
   }
   
   .nav-header{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-title{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-btn{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-check{
   display: none;
   }
   
   #nav-check{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-links{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-header{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav2 a {
   display: none;  
   }
   
   .nav-header a{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-title a{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-btn a {
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-check a{
   display: none;
   }
   
   #nav-check a{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-links a{
   display: none;
   }
   
   .nav-header a{
   display: none;
   }
   
   body > #header{position:fixed;}
   #header {
       width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       z-index:9000;
       color: #000000;
       WHITE BG // color/ #8c8c8c;
       font-size: 25px;
       text-align: left;
       font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
       left: 15px;
       top: 25px;
       transition: all 0.5s linear;
       transition: height 0.5s ease;
       -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
       -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
       -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
       transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
       -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
       -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
       -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
       transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
       -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
          -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
           -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
            -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
               animation: fadein 2s;
       
   }
   
   #navigation {
   width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 9000;
       text-decoration: none!important;
       list-style-type: none;
       color: #006CFF;
       font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
       font-size: 15px;
       text-align: right;
       margin: 22px -20px;
       -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
          -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
           -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
            -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
               animation: fadein 2s;
   
      
   }



   .feedback {
text-align: center;
font-size: 22px;
color: #494949;

}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: bolder;
color: #494949;

}
```

```html
<doctype! html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Oops.. Dead End</title>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-136743580-1"></script>
<div id="header">adamferreira</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <a class="nav" href="index.html"> Return Home</a>
    </ul>
    </div>


<div class="headerBackground"></div>
<body>

<div class="container" data-aos="ease-in-out-back" data-aos="zoom out">
<h1>Looks like this page doesn't exist</h1>
<h1 class="feedback">Please double-check you are entering the correct information in your address bar.<br> This page may also have been moved, deleted or a feature may not be available to you.</h1>


</head>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the question is a little bit confused... but one problem I see is that you are using 2 `<h1>` tags. That means that your CSS style for `h1` will affect both tags. Also, it is not a good practice to have more than one `<h1>` on the same page. That goes against SEO principles, clean code, etc...

Comment: `<h1>` is a size of heading, it doesn't mean it's the first or the only one on a page. You could have 5 chapters on a page, each one using `h1` for the chapter title, `h2` size for the subtitle. Where have you heard it's not a good idea?

Comment: @Adam Ferreira, I'm seeing it in the center of the screen. Do you have a screenshot of what you want it to look like? The text is centered on my browser.

Comment: @Bman70,  `<h1>` tags are used as a convention to determine the main topic of a specific page. Multiple chapters are used defined with `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc.
https://www.quora.com/How-many-H1-tags-can-you-have-on-a-single-web-page

Comment: Besides that, he has a CSS style for `<h1>` and another one for `.feedback`, which is also an `<h1>`. That means that one style is overlapping with the other. That's probably the reason for him to say:
"padding works but both of the h1's start to separate in a large gap"

Comment: Cool thanks for the link, I've never heard of that. I don't think I've ever used those tags in a page, I prefer CSS styling. But I can't imagine using `<h1>` for one chapter heading and `<h2>`, `<h3>` for others, the size difference is so drastic. You'd have to restyle with CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing well. Following is the code change that I'd suggest in this case:

```
<div class="new">
 <h1>Looks like this page doesn't exist</h1>
 <h2 class="feedback">Please double-check you are entering the correct 
 information in your address bar.<br> This page may also have been moved, 
 deleted or a feature may not be available to you.</h1> 
</div>
```

I've created a new div with class name "new" and altered the second tag (changed it to h2) as per standards. And most importantly, added the following in the CSS:

```
.new {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I hope this helps.